# Check if fields implement some interface and pass them as arguments

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have one class with some objects stored in private fields. I want to create a function of the class that checks all its private fields to check if its type implements a certain interface, and if so, pass them as arguments by reference to some other fucntion. Something like this:

```
Public Class OneClass
    Private _fieldA As ObjectA
    Private _fieldB As ObjectB
    '... some other objects stored in private fiels

    Public Function MyFunction()
        'psedocode I want to write
        For Each field In Me
            If field implements SomeInterface
                DoSomethings(field)
            End If
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that I have to pass the object stored in the field as reference to some function. Is possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking for is possible using Reflection but I just want to make sure that it's necessary first.  You know the type of each field when you write the code so wouldn't you know whether they implement this interface then?  Is it that the actual objects might be some derived typed rather then the specific type of the field and that derived type might or might not implement the interface?  If you field was BaseClass and you assigned an object to it of DerivedClass and DerivedClass implements ISomeInterface while BaseClass does not; is that the sort of thing you're trying to detect?

Comment: Ummm... thinking about your comment I've realized that I don't need to complicate things so much! Thank you very much, I would like to mark your comment as the correct aswer!